# Unexpected response code 503 from Google Maps in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use google maps api in my android project. previously, the project was working fine, but now the message appears "Unexpected response code 503 for [https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api"](https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api%22)

apparently I get an email from google.

No Use in Customer Application Directed To Children. Customer will not use the Google Maps Core Services in a Customer Application that would be deemed to be a “Web site or online service directed to children” under the Children’s Online Privacy Protection Act (COPPA).

how do i solve this?

Comment: are you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Change your package name and add it to your app in firebase.

Answer (score 0):

The email means that your API key was used in an application directed to children which is in violation of the terms of service specifically in item [3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services (i) No Use in Customer Application Directed To Children](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#3.-license.)

I suggest that you file a support case to Google Maps Platform to solve this issue: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#creating-a-support-case